# In Visual Studio 2019, the WCF service (AJAX enabled) is not in Add --> New Item

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a Rest web service and am new to Visual Studio 2019. After creating the project, I am trying to get WCF service (AJAX enabled) by right clicking the project and going to Add -> New Item. However, I do not see this service anywhere. Am I suppose to download this template somewhere? How do I get this to work??

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB4jA.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2019, I followed first steps of the following walktrough from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/create-an-ajax-wcf-asp-net-client

The item `WCF Service (Ajax enabled)` does show up in the items list when I add an item to my project. So it does seem to be available in Visual Studio 2019.

Perhaps you are using a wrong Visual Studio project type, which filters out that item? For example, I suppose that .NET Core projects cannot use WCF technology, because WCF is probably only available in .NET Framework. However, looking at the file structure of the project in your screenshot, I suppose you are using a .NET Framework project that should support the use of WCF technology...

You might want to check your Visual Studio installation by running the Visual Studio installer (from the start menu), hitting the `Modify` button of your displayed installation, selecting the `ASP.NET and web development` workload (if not already selected), and check the corresponding options in the `Installation details` pane of of the `Workloads` tab. I suppose that at least the option `Windows Communication Foundation` should be selected if you want to use WCF functionality in your projects.

I personally don't want to think a lot about these kind of issues. So when I installed Visual Studio 2019 a few days ago, I simply selected (almost) all options in the installation details as well...

Comment: Thank you very much Bart. It worked! I did as you suggested and surely enough Windows Communication Foundation wasn't checked to be installed. Initially, I had thought this option would automatically be a part of the VS package.

Comment: Yes same. I had the ASP.NET and .NET desktop development checked but couldn't find WCF. So switched from 'Workload' tab to 'Individual components' tab and typed WCF which gave the option to tick 'Windows Communication Foundation'

Answer (score 3):

please run VisualStudio Installer , after that add on Windows Communication Foundation Component into VS 2019.
Regards

Comment: Hey, and welcome to SO! This was previously answered in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989457/6707985] this answer as well. Either explain what makes your answer different from the linked one or delete this answer and in the future only add answers that add something new.

Answer (score 0):

If Ajax enabled WCF service doesn't show up in your add new items dialog box check if you have that installed by searching ***WCF service*** in the search bar. If it isn't installed you can install it and it should show up in your add new item's dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is in framework, more precisely in using any framework which version is below 5. Make sure you choose the right one while creating project.