# WCF service not available in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, class-library

I have created a class library project in Visual Studio 2019.

I am trying to Add New item - WCF service to this Class library project, but it is not available.

Note - I have installed Windows Communication Foundation from Visual Studio Installer.

Please let me know how to add New Item - WCF service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Visual Studio 2019, the WCF service (AJAX enabled) is not in Add --> New Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989165/in-visual-studio-2019-the-wcf-service-ajax-enabled-is-not-in-add-new-item)

Comment: @gunr2171 - Like I said, I am able to create WCF service project. But I want to Add New Item - WCF service to existing Class Library project. And it is not available.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a reference to a service or do you mean you want your class library to host a service?

Comment: @Crowcoder - I want to add a new WCF service in Class Library

Comment: Taken literally, that doesn't make any sense. You cannot add a service into a class library. Maybe if you describe how you were going to use it we could help.

Comment: @Crowcoder - sorry. I think I got it. I am new to WCF and learning from video tutorials, where he created a Class Library and then added a WCF service class.
Since I am not able to do that, I am able to create a new project with WCF service class, which is also a class library.